# Average of Top n per Group SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, average, top-n

I'm working on a problem of finding mean processing times.  I'm trying to eliminate outlier data by essentially performing a average on only the best 80% of the data.

I am struggling trying to adapt existing Top N per Group solutions to perform averaging per group.  Using SQL Server 2008.

Here is a sample of what the table looks like:

```
    OpID  |  ProcessMin  |  Datestamp
    2     |  234         |  2012-01-26 09:07:29.000
    2     |  222         |  2012-01-26 10:04:22.000
    3     |  127         |  2012-01-26 11:09:51.000
    3     |  134         |  2012-01-26 05:02:11.000
    3     |  566         |  2012-01-26 05:27:31.000
    4     |  234         |  2012-01-26 04:08:41.000
```

I want it to take the lowest 80% of the ProcessMin for **each** OpID, and take the average of that array.  Any help would be appreciated!

*** UPDATE ***

Given the following table:

```
OpID  ProcessMin   Datestamp
602   33           46:54.0
602   36           38:59.0
602   37           18:45.0
602   39           22:01.0
602   41           36:43.0
602   42           33:00.0
602   49           03:48.0
602   51           22:08.0
602   69           39:15.0
602   105          59:56.0
603   13           34:07.0
603   18           07:17.0
603   31           57:07.0
603   39           01:52.0
603   39           01:02.0
603   40           40:10.0
603   46           22:56.0
603   47           11:03.0
603   48           40:13.0
603   56           25:01.0
```

I would expect this output:

```
OptID   ProcessMin
602     41
603     34.125
```

Notice that since there are 10 data points for each OpID, it would only average the lowest 8 values (80%).

Comment: This is just another subquery, show us the expected results with more sample data.  At the end of the day its just a group by opid

Comment: @JonH -- I added some more samples and an output as an example above.  I tried doing a subquery, but I'm failing to setup the logic such that the Top applies to each OpID's set of ProcessMin, rather than the entire table.  Sorry this might be a bit of a rookie mistake.  I think this may be able to be accomplished with partitioning, but my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ntile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)

```
select OpID,
       avg(ProcessMin) as ProcessMin
from
  (
    select OpID,
           ProcessMin,
           ntile(5) over(partition by OpID order by ProcessMin) as nt
    from YourTable
  ) as T
where nt <= 4
group by OpID
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66746/average-of-top-n-per-group-sql-server)

If ProcessMin is an `integer` you can do `avg(cast(ProcessMin as float)) as ProcessMin` to get the decimal average value.

Comment: Mikael, looks perfect man thanks a lot!  Just to clarify, the ntile(5) is essentially dividing the dataset into 5 sections, and the nt<=4 is including the lowest 4/5ths ==> 80%?

Comment: @EricHill - Yes thats exactly it.

Comment: Thanks so much, you're a lifesaver.  I think I finally understand how the OVER PARTITION works now too!